# OpenCV Build ok, debug throws error, runs fine from .exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

Using Visual Studio 2010, OpenCV 2.2.2, Windows 7 64x

My code builds successfully then when it goes into debug I get the following error:

```
First-chance exception at 0x75f0c41f in MachineVisionHW0.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x002dec90..
Unhandled exception at 0x75f0c41f in MachineVisionHW0.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x002dec90..
```

Then I end debug, go to the file directory and run the built executable and it runs fine.   Does anybody know how to fix this? It isn't keeping me from building my code, but it is incredibly inconvenient.  I will include an example of the code that is doing this below.

```
int main(){
    cv::Mat image1 = cv::imread("img1.JPG", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    cv::namedWindow("Sample1");
    cv::imshow("Sample1", image1);
    cv::waitKey(0); 

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @ChrisO this is the first time i have used c or c++ in years, and when i did in the past I don't even know if i ever learned try/catch.  upon looking around online, it looks like you pass an argument to catch, implying that you know the problem.  I have no idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you get the unhandled exception *before* main?

If not, then your code is somehow doing something to raise the exception.  Put a breakpoint on the first line, then hit F5, then once at the breakpoint, step through the code one line at a time to see which one causes the exception, F10 key to do this.

My gut feeling is that when running from the debugger, the `cv::imread` is failing since it is not finding the img1.jpg from the expected location, the current working directory is that of the solution file, not of the debug output build dir.  You can do a quick test and copy the img1.jpg to the dir containing the sln file and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Instead of copying `img1.jpg` you can just provide absolute path to it.

Comment: @cyriel You can certainly do that, but using absolute paths can cause problems with deployment scenarios.

Comment: of course, you are right. I suggested it only for test, not as a final solution.

Comment: @ChrisO Sorry I have been busy over the weekend and getting caught up at school.  Just now got back to my question.

Comment: @ChrisO I tried changing the file location and that made it so I couldnt even run from the file directory.  When I ran the debugger line by line with the breakpoint as suggested, I ran into the error here: `cv::filter2D(image1, imageDone1, ddepth, kernel1, anchor, 0);`

Comment: The image was in the wrong folder, but it doesn't need to be in the folder with the solution file.  It should be in the same folder as the source code and property files.  The folder will be named the same thing as the solution file though